# how to query date field between two days in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I know how to do it in Oracle, but I can't find same function in mySQL.
try to google it..but can't find it.

I have a table, there is a field name "create_date" , attribute is datetime
so field value format looks like "2009-09-25 11:48:24"

Now I want to add date condition , I want to find create_date between 2009/09/01 to 2009/10/14
my sql command:
 **where 1=1 and date_format(create_date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '01/09/2009' AND '14/10/2009**'

it's OK..I can get rowdata 
but when I change begin date to 2009/09/30, end date is same

**date_format(create_date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '30/09/2009' AND '14/10/2009'**

and no result...
but if I change begin date to 2009/10/01 , I can get result again.
I jsut want to know what happend? it should fine to

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a function (`DATE_FORMAT`) on the wrong thing: you should `STR_TO_DATE` your parameters, and make MySQL do a date range comparison, rather than converting the row value to a string and doing a string range comparison (I'm not even sure that makes sense or works in all cases). Try this:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM my_table t
 WHERE t.create_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2009/09/01', '%Y/%m/%d')
                         AND STR_TO_DATE('2009/10/01', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

I think that would work better.